# Job Inquiry Bot for Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to create a bot that a user can DM to start a "job" inquiry.
Example:

A user messages the bot with !inquiry, then the bot asks questions about the job such as if it's a personal project or for a company, then what is the company or personal projects twitter, it will then ask what type of service they are requesting by supplying options and based on that option the bot will respond with "Please explain what you have in mind for your new xxx job"

Then once the user answers all those questions the bot sends an embed with what they answered.

I was thinking of using MessageCollector but I got stuck with how to do the logic. I have the bot responding to the user so I understand how to send messages through DM to a user. just don't quite understand how to implement the rest. I need a little push.

```
client.on("message", async (msg) => {
  if (!msg.content.startsWith(prefix) || msg.author.bot) return;

if (msg.channel.type === "dm") {
 const args = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
 const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
 const discordUser = msg.author.tag;

if (command !== "order") {
  try {
    sendFailMessage(msg, "wrongCommand");
  } catch (e) {
    console.warn("Failed sending Fail Message");
  }
} else {
  msg.channel.startTyping(1);
  msg.author.send();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What code do you have so far?

Comment: I added my code in. So the rest after this I just started over because it started to get to messy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made something similar before so incase you want the full code and context: https://github.com/karizma/ravenxi/blob/master/commands/showcase/apply.js

But here's it rewritten for your context:
(note it's def not optimized since idk your context code, and you are passing variables for every call, but if you know js decently which you should if you are gonna use a libary, it shouldn't be too hard to better the code)

```js
function sendNexQuestion(index, channel, questions, replys) {
    return channel.send(questions[index])
        .then(() => channel.awaitMessages(() => true, { max: 1, time: 30000, errors: ["time"] }))
        .then(reply => {
            const content = reply.first().content;
            if (content === prefix + "cancel") throw "Self-Cancel";
            if (content === prefix + "redo") {
                replys.length = 0;
                return sendNextQuestion(0, channel, questions, replys);
            }

            replys.push(content);
            return index >= questions.length - 1 ? new Promise(res => res(replys)) : sendNextQuestion(index + 1, channel, questions, replys);
        }).catch(err => {
            if (err === "Self-Cancel") {
                //user canceled
            }

            channel.send("Application Canceled");
        });
}

client.on("message", async (msg) => {
    if (!msg.content.startsWith(prefix) || msg.author.bot) return;
    if (msg.channel.type === "dm") {
        const args = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
        const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
        const questions = ["Why do you want this?", "Question 2"];

        if (command === "inquiry") {
            sendNexQuestion(0, msg.channel, questions, []).then(replys => {
                //array of replys
            })
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: After answering first question, I get Application Canceled. How can I fix this?

Comment: Hey sorry I forgot to respond, are you still having this issue?